# Silex form validator translations not being set from Yaml

Tags: php, forms, translation, silex

```
// Forms
$app->register(new FormServiceProvider());
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\ValidatorServiceProvider());

// Locale
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\TranslationServiceProvider(), array(
  'locale' => 'en',
  'locale_fallback' => 'en'
));

$app['translator']->addLoader('yaml', new Symfony\Component\Translation\Loader\YamlFileLoader());
$app['translator']->addResource('yaml', $app['root_dir'] .'/config/poseidon/locales/en.yml', 'en');
$app['translator']->addResource('yaml', $app['root_dir'] .'/config/poseidon/locales/validators.en.yml', 'en', 'validators');
```

This is how part of my index.php looks. The messages domain is fine however the validators domain is not. This is because the default form translations in the xlf files mean the yml file I am loading does not apply.

For example if I edit the xlf file and delete:

This value should not be blank.

Then my yml file:

```
# validators.en.yml

This value should not be blank.: This is a required field
```

Will be loaded and this key will be added to the validators array. However it seems as long as those default xlf files are being loaded, nothing from my yaml file will be able to overwrite the validators translation domain.

Any help would be appreciated as I am out of ideas as to why this is happening. Thanks.

EDIT:

This is actually the opposite way round to what I thought, I added in:

```
echo $app['translator']->trans(
                        'This value should not be blank.',
                        array(), 
                        'validators'
                    );
```

Directly after the translator adds the resource and got the expected result which means that when the FormServiceProvider is being loaded the default xlf file is the one overwriting what currently exists in the message catalogue validators domain.

So if anyone know how to prevent it from doing this that would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => xliff
            [1] => /Silex/vendor/symfony/form/Symfony/Component/Form/Resources/translations/validators.en.xlf
            [2] => validators
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => xliff
            [1] => /Silex/vendor/symfony/validator/Symfony/Component/Validator/Resources/translations/validators.en.xlf
            [2] => validators
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => yaml
            [1] => /Silex/web/../config/poseidon/locales/validators.en.yml
            [2] => validators
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => yaml
            [1] => /Silex/web/../config/poseidon/locales/en.yml
            [2] => messages
        )

)
```

This isn't the most ideal solution but I edited the Translator class and reversed the array as shown above to make sure the xliff files were loaded before the yml files and now everything works fine.

I do need to find a solution that does not edit the Translator class.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this solution on the Silex Github page](https://github.com/silexphp/Silex/issues/1041):
Registration (in your case in index.php):

```
$app['locale'] = 'fr';

$app->register(new TranslationServiceProvider());
$app->register(new ValidatorServiceProvider());

$app['validator'];
$app['translator'] = $app->share(
    $app->extend(
        'translator',
        function ($translator, $app) {
            $translator->addLoader('yaml', new YamlFileLoader());
            $translator->addResource('yaml', 'path/to/validators.fr.yml', 'fr', 'validators');

            return $translator;
        }
    )
);
```

Calling up `$app['validator']` before `$app['translator']` triggers it's register method, so the yaml files get loaded after.

I had the same problem, this solved it.

Answer (score 0):

in recent silex versions, use

```
$app['locale'] = 'fr';

$app->register(new TranslationServiceProvider());
$app->register(new ValidatorServiceProvider());

$app['validator'];
$app['translator'] = $app->extend(
    'translator',
    function ($translator, $app) {
        $translator->addLoader('yaml', new YamlFileLoader());
        $translator->addResource('yaml', 'path/to/validators.fr.yml', 'fr', 'validators');

        return $translator;
    }
);
```

without the «share» method